# How to render a view from my "posts" application onto my Home page in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I successfully added the "Post" form using `<%= render 'posts/form' %>`, but I don't want the form, just the Show view. I want the Home page to show any posts that are put up, but I don't want the posts to be created from there.

EDIT: I've got a static page as my home page, and I want my "posts" to show up in the body of the homepage, like how a regular Blog website is set up. I plan on adding a log in function later to access the create/read/update/delete portion. For example I used the code `<%= render 'posts/form' %>` to make the form appear in the body of the homepage, but instead I want to only show the completed "posts".

Comment: You need to add a better explanation to what your asking. I get generally what your aiming at, but can't answer unless you say more.

Comment: Agree ^ add more explanation.

Comment: Can you post the Ruby code for your HomeController?

Answer (score 0):

config/routes.rb

```
get 'posts#index'
root 'posts#index'
```

Also remove `resources :posts` if it's in your routes file.

This will make it so that pages with your Post forms are not accessible.

You can delete your form view files too if you'd like; however, you might want to use them later. Same goes for the new/create/edit/update actions in your posts_controller.rb file.

You might want to add some authentication for the pages that contain the forms instead? I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the home controller to query for all the posts, and then change view:

**HomeController**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Posts.all
  end
end
```

**views/home/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Posts</h1>

<% @posts.each do |post|
  <h2><%= post.title %></h2>
  <div>
    <%= post.body %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is basic [Ruby on Rails controller work](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html).

You can then utilize partials to DRY up your views:

**views/posts/_post.html.erb**

```
<h2><%= post.title %></h2>
<div>
  <%= post.body %>
</div>
```

Now `views/home/index.html.erb` becomes:

```
<h1>Posts</h1>

<% @posts.each do |post|
  <%= render partial: 'posts/_post', locals: {post: post} %>
<% end %>
```

And `views/posts/show.html.erb` becomes:

```
<%= render partial: 'posts/_post', locals: {post: @post} %>
```

(assuming `@post` is the blog post in `PostsController#show`)

Comment: That was it! Thank you! Although I will note that I had to change                 ``<% @posts.each do |post|``  to ``<% @posts.each do |post| %>``